# [Facebook][Graph-API] Facebook doesn't return all posts for a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently testing to get some posts from a media page for a specific time range:

- page: https://www.facebook.com/LExpress
- since: **2017-09-06 11:00:00** +0000 (strtotime -> 1504688400)
- until: **2017-09-06 18:00:00** +0000 (strtotime -> 1504713600)

But surprisingly some posts are missing from Facebook response.

**Here is the facebook request used to get the posts list:**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=LExpress%2Fposts%3Fsince%3D1504688400%26until%3D1504713600&version=v2.11

This returns only these three results:

```
 "data": [
        {
          "created_time": "2017-09-06T15:05:00+0000",
          "message": "Casernes de pompiers inondées, hôtels dévastés : l'ouragan Irma s'est abattu sur les îles de Saint-Barthélemy et Saint-Martin",
          "id": "9359316996_10155287552551997"
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2017-09-06T14:15:00+0000",
          "message": "Le gouvernement aussi a fait sa rentrée des classes",
          "id": "9359316996_10155287360111997"
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2017-09-06T09:45:00+0000",
          "message": "Persécutés, des dizaines de milliers de Rohingyas fuient la Birmanie",
          "id": "9359316996_10155286897911997"
        }
      ]
```

**But where is the post published at 2017-09-06 12:56:32 ??**

The following post has been published at **2017-09-06 12:56:32** +0000 and should be returned by Facebook in the specified date range:

- since: **2017-09-06 11:00:00** +0000
- until: **2017-09-06 18:00:00** +0000

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10155287271171997%3Ffields%3Did%2Cupdated_time%2Ccreated_time%2Cname&version=v2.11

```
{
  "id": "10155287271171997",
  "updated_time": "2017-09-06T12:56:32+0000",
  "created_time": "2017-09-06T12:56:32+0000",
  "name": "⭕ ALERTE — Ouragan Irma : black-out total sur les îles de Saint-Barthélémy et Saint-Martin

Centrales EDF hors-service, casernes de pompiers inondées

Suivez notre direct"
}
```

Why is that? Any thoughts?

Thx!

PS: as it is `photos` I also tried to get it from /photos route, but we don't get any results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that Facebook will return a maximum of 600 posts per pages as explained in the page's feed `limitations` paragraph :

> The API will return a maximum of 600 ranked, published posts per year.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#read

Answer (score 1):

Like what Ben Tazulev said, with the `/{page-id}/posts` endpoint there a limitation:

> The API will return approximately 600 ranked, published posts per year. For all posts query the `/{page_id}/published_posts` endpoint.

-> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#read

But when I tried to gather all my post with the `/{page_id}/published_posts` it worked!

-> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/published_posts/